# No of days between 2 dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the sample data I have employee wise tour dates with month break up sorted by dates in ascending order. I would like to calculate days. Any formula suggestion please?

Conditions:
1. 1 date for 1 month and 1 employee
2. Should include start date also.

From the below example I may explain my requirement for one employee no.1531. All my dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format.

```
| 1531 | 3-4-2018  | 3-4-2018 | 4    |
| 1531 | 3-4-2018  | 4-4-2018 | 4    |
| 1531 | 3-4-2018  | 7-4-2018 | 4    |
| 1531 | 22-4-2018 | 2-5-2018 | 4    |
| 1531 | 3-5-2018  | 4-5-2018 | 5    |
| 1532 | 1-4-2018  | 2-4-2018 | 4    |
| 1532 | 22-4-2018 | 2-5-2018 | 4    |
| 1532 | 3-5-2018  | 4-5-2018 | 5    |
```

1531 employee were started his tour on 03/04/2018 and concluded on the same day for one location. Again he started on the same day 03/04/2018 and concluded on 04/04/2018 for 2nd location. Again the person mentioned he started on 03/04/2018 and concluded on 07/04/2018 for another location. In the above said the date 03/04/2018 were entered trice which was not right, but because I don't have control to stop this in application the entries were made by employee wrongly. So I want excel to consider the date 03/04/2018 as one time only while calculating days. I was tried my best to arrive the days but could not. I have attached my formula as separate file for your kind reference. Kindly look into this and give solution. Even this formula i got through from one among the stack overflow member only. In this i was not comfortable to get my dynamic starting date.

I have asked the similar question earlier also but i have not received any answer against my expectations

Comment: Kindly provide your sample data.

Comment: @JvdV i am not able to attach files as it shows 10 reputation required to post images. What could be done? To paste an image about my question.

Comment: You don't need to attach files, you could also attach a screenshot or provide some markdown sample data using [this for example](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Simply type two or three examples of the dates you are working with : 12/12/11  and 15/12/11 etc with the calculations you have tried

Comment: Emp no in col A starts from cell a1 as follows 1531,1531,1531,1531,1531,1532,1532,1532. And Depart Date starts from cell B1 row wise 03/04/2018,03/04/2018,03/04/2018,22/04/2018,03/05/2018,01/04/2018,22/04/2018,03/05/2018. Arrival Date starts from Cell C1 by row as like 03/04/2018,04/04/2018,07/04/2018,02/05/2018,04/05/2018,02/04/2018,02/05/2018 and 04/05/2018. Finally month column from Cell D1 row wise as like 4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5.

Comment: My formula was =days(c2,max(if(a2=$a$1:$a1,$c$1:$c1),b2))+if(max(if(a2=$a$1:$a1,$c$1:$c1))<b2,1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `Date 1 - Date 2`. Most libraries in most languages should have the - operator overridden. 
If not, convert both dates to epoch timestamps(seconds) and then divide it by (24*60):

```
Date Date1 = new Date(03/04/2018);
Date Date2 = new Date(04/04/2018);

int days = (Date2.toTimeStamp() - Date1.toTimeStamp()) / (24*60);
```

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response. But I need to calculate only days between dates why should i convert it into time. Also I am about to attach a image for my question which i am unable to do as it requires atleast 10 reputation it shows.

Comment: If you do not convert it into an intermediary representation, you would have to take care of all the edge cases: month changes, year changes, etc